# Stm32 spi write on rising edge and read on falling edge, possible?

Tags: stm32

i have application ic which needs to write on rising egde and read on falling edge . Write now i get both on rising egde?

I am using bidirectional mode so only 3 wires 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> needs to write on rising egde and read on falling edge

Look at the SPI timing diagram in the Reference Manual. (This is for the F4 series, but AFAIK other series have compatible SPI controllers)

[image: SPI timing diagram]

It does what you want when `CPHA == 1` and `CPOL == 0`. Data lines are written at the rising edge, and captured at the falling edge of `SCK`.

Comment: But it looks both read and write is done on rising edge for cpha =1 and cpol=1